# How to check object is a Set?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `Set` to handle my task. But when I debugged, I got

> `mySet.has` is not a function

So my question is how to check if It's a `Set`. Like for the `Array` has `Array.isArray(obj)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**instanceof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

```js
let a = new Set()
let b = [1,2]

console.log(a instanceof Set)
console.log(b instanceof Set)
```

> **On side note :-**

You can also use `[] instanceof Array`. However, `Array.isArray` was created for a specific purpose: avoiding an issue with instanceof. Namely, `window1.Array != window2.array;` thus, `new window1.Array() instanceof window2.Array == false`. Same logic holds for Set. As long as you don't mess with multiple global environments, instanceof is fine. If you do, `b.toString() == "[object Set]"` might be better. Thanks to ***@andman*** for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use `instanceof`.

read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

```js
let s1 = new Set()
let s2 = ['a','b','c']

console.log(s1 instanceof Set)
console.log(s2 instanceof Set)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility for this check could be using [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

```js
let a = new Set([1,2]);
let b = [1,2];

console.log("a is a Set? " + (a.constructor === Set));
console.log("b is a Set? " + (b.constructor === Set));
```